# Repeating OpenGL-es texture bound to hills in cocos2d 2.0

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

## ORIGINAL ARTICLE

I am in the process of trying to implement [raywenderlich's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3888/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-part-1) on generating hills with repeating striped coordinates using cocos2d, This article was written for Cocos2D 1.0, and as I am trying to port it to Cocos2D 2.0 This means updating it for openGl-es 2. So far everything has worked perfectly, However I am having problems with getting the texture of the hill to repeat properly...

Here is my code:

Sending the hills the texture:

```
CCSprite *stripes = [self stripedSpriteWithColor1:color3 color2:color4 textureSize:512 stripes:nStripes];
    stripes.position = ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2);
    ccTexParams tp2 = {GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR, GL_REPEAT, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE};
    [stripes.texture setTexParameters:&tp2];
    _terrain.stripes = stripes;
    _backgroundTerrain.stripes = stripes;
```

Generating texture:

```
-(CCSprite *)stripedSpriteWithColor1:(ccColor4F)c1 color2:(ccColor4F)c2 textureSize:(float)textureSize stripes:(int) nStripes {
    // 1: Create new CCRenderTexture
    CCRenderTexture *rt = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:textureSize height:textureSize];

    // 2: Call CCRenderTexture:begin

    [rt beginWithClear:c1.r g:c1.g b:c1.b a:c1.a];

    // 3: Draw into texture
    //OpenGL gradient

    NSLog(@"Strip color is: %f : %f : %f", c2.r,c2.g,c2.b);

    CGPoint vertices[nStripes*6];
    ccColor4F colors[nStripes*6];
    int nVertices = 0;
    float x1 = -textureSize;
    float x2;
    float y1 = textureSize;
    float y2 = 0;
    float dx = textureSize / nStripes * 2;
    float stripeWidth = dx/2;
    ccColor4F stripColor = (ccColor4F){c2.r,c2.g,c2.b,c2.a};
    for (int i=0; i<nStripes; i++) {
        x2 = x1 + textureSize;
        colors[nVertices] = stripColor;
        vertices[nVertices++] = ccpMult(CGPointMake(x1, y1), CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR());
        colors[nVertices] = stripColor;
        vertices[nVertices++] = ccpMult(CGPointMake(x1+stripeWidth, y1), CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR());
        colors[nVertices] = stripColor;
        vertices[nVertices++] = ccpMult(CGPointMake(x2, y2), CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR());
        colors[nVertices] = stripColor;
        vertices[nVertices++] = vertices[nVertices-3];
        colors[nVertices] = stripColor;
        vertices[nVertices++] = vertices[nVertices-3];
        colors[nVertices] = stripColor;
        vertices[nVertices++] = ccpMult(CGPointMake(x2+stripeWidth, y2), CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR());
        x1 += dx;
    }


    [self.shaderProgram use];


    ccGLEnableVertexAttribs(kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position  | kCCVertexAttribFlag_Color);

    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Color, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, colors);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, (GLsizei)nVertices);

    //Gradient

    float gradientAlpha = 0.2;
    nVertices = 0;

    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){0,0,0,0};
    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(textureSize, 0);
    colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){0,0,0,0};
    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(0, textureSize);
    colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){0,0,0,gradientAlpha};
    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(textureSize, textureSize);
    colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){0,0,0,gradientAlpha};





    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Color, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, colors);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0, (GLsizei)nVertices);



    // Highlighting

    float borderWidth = textureSize/8;
    float borderAlpha = 0.1f;
    nVertices = 0;

    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    colors [nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){1,1,1,borderAlpha};
    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(textureSize*CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR(),0);
    colors [nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){1,1,1,borderAlpha};

    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(0, borderWidth*CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR());
    colors [nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){0,0,0,0};
    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(textureSize*CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR(),borderWidth*CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR());
    colors [nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){0,0,0,0};

    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Color, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, colors);
    glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)nVertices);



    //Noise 
    CCSprite *noise = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"noise.png"];
    [noise setBlendFunc:(ccBlendFunc){GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO}];
    noise.position = ccp(textureSize/2, textureSize/2);
    [noise visit];


    [rt end];
    // Return texture sprite
    return [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:rt.sprite.texture];

}
```

Getting TexCoords for bounding the stripes to the hill:

```
- (void)resetHillVertices {

    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    static int prevFromKeyPointI = -1;
    static int prevToKeyPointI = -1;

    // key points interval for drawing
    while (_hillKeyPoints[_fromKeyPointI+1].x < _offsetX-winSize.width/self.scale) {
        _fromKeyPointI++;
    }
    while (_hillKeyPoints[_toKeyPointI].x < _offsetX+winSize.width*3/2/self.scale) {
        _toKeyPointI++;
    }

    if (prevFromKeyPointI != _fromKeyPointI || prevToKeyPointI != _toKeyPointI) {
        _nHillVertices = 0;
        _nBorderVertices = 0;
        CGPoint p0, p1, pt0, pt1;
        p0 = _hillKeyPoints[_fromKeyPointI];
        for (int i=_fromKeyPointI+1; i<_toKeyPointI+1; i++) {
            p1 = _hillKeyPoints[i];

            // triangle strip between p0 and p1
            int hSegments = floorf((p1.x-p0.x)/kHillSegmentWidth);
            float dx = (p1.x - p0.x) / hSegments;
            float da = M_PI / hSegments;
            float ymid = (p0.y + p1.y) / 2;
            float ampl = (p0.y - p1.y) / 2;
            pt0 = p0;
            _borderVertices[_nBorderVertices++] = pt0;
            for (int j=1; j<hSegments+1; j++) {
                pt1.x = p0.x + j*dx;
                pt1.y = ymid + ampl * cosf(da*j);
                _borderVertices[_nBorderVertices++] = pt1;

                _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt0.x, 0);
                _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(pt0.x/512, 1.0f);
                _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt1.x, 0);
                _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(pt1.x/512, 1.0f);

                _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt0.x, pt0.y);
                _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(pt0.x/512, 0);
                _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt1.x, pt1.y);
                _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(pt1.x/512, 0);

                pt0 = pt1;
            }

            p0 = p1;
        }

        prevFromKeyPointI = _fromKeyPointI;
        prevToKeyPointI = _toKeyPointI;
        [self resetBox2DBody];
    }

}
```

Drawing the texture:

```
- (void) draw {


    self.shaderProgram = [[CCShaderCache sharedShaderCache] programForKey:kCCShader_PositionTexture];
    CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP();
    ccGLBlendFunc( CC_BLEND_SRC, CC_BLEND_DST ); //TB 25-08-12: Allows change of blend function

    ccGLEnableVertexAttribs(kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position  | kCCVertexAttribFlag_TexCoords);

    ccGLBindTexture2D(_stripes.texture.name);
    // Assign the vertices array to the 'position' attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _hillVertices);

    // Assign the texCoords array to the 'TexCoords' attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _hillTexCoords);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)_nHillVertices);
}
```

The problem I'm having is this: after a certain number of repeats the texture starts to degrade in quality, like so:

[image: Degradation]

Is there any way to get the texture to repeat without degradation?

## EDIT 1:

I've veen doing more analysis into how the texture degrades, it turns out it doesn't do it continuously, but degrades with power of 2 repetitions so it degrades for the first time on the first repeat then after 2 repeats, then 4, 8, 16, 32 and so on... It also seems that the vertical bands that start to appear that can be seen in the image double in width each time the image degrades in quality. Also on each degradation the frame rate of the game decreases substantially so I'm starting to think this is probably a memory issue.

## EDIT 2:

My best guess at why this is happening so far is because the -draw method for the terrain is continually making GL_TRAINGLE_STRIP, and not deleting them once they are off-screen causing a build up in the memory usage of the terrain, causing the degradation and frame rate drop.

[image: Degradation Doubling]

## UPDATE 1

I have solved two of the problems that were occurring with my texture generation...

### Solving Misalignment

IN the sprite generation method this:

```
float x1 = -textureSize;
float x2;
float y1 = textureSize;
float y2 = 0;
float dx = textureSize / nStripes * 2;
```

to this:

```
float x1 = -winSize.width;
float x2;
float y1 = winSize.height;
float y2 = 0;
float dx = winSize.width / nStripes * 2;
```

I realised that this was totally unrelated to the main error, rather it was due to my stripes for some reason not appearing at a 45 degree angle, which causes them to misalign on repeat. I tried to think of reasons for this, and finally fixed it by assuming that the textures coordinate origin was at the top left corner of the screen as opposed to the top left corner of the texture.

### Solving Degradation (Kind of)

I had an inkling that the image degradation was occurring due to the large amounts of repetitions of the texture, due to a similar reason as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370074/opengl-es-2-0-texture-distortion-on-large-geometry-gl-repeat/11371462#comment19333122_11371462) Although I may be wrong on that front!

To solve this in the resetHillVertices I set it up so the texCoords are always between 0 and 1 meaning that the texture bound to the hills is always the first repetition of the texture. I implemented this like so:

```
for (int j=1; j<hSegments+1; j++) {
            pt1.x = p0.x + j*dx;
            pt1.y = ymid + ampl * cosf(da*j);
            _borderVertices[_nBorderVertices++] = pt1;
            float xTex0 = pt0.x/512;
            float xTex1 = pt1.x/512;
            while (xTex0 > 1) { // makes sure texture coordinates are always within the first repetition of texture
                xTex0 -= 1;
            }
            while (xTex1 > 1) {
                xTex1 -= 1;
            }
            _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt0.x, 0);
            _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(xTex0, 1.0);
            _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt1.x, 0);
            _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(xTex1, 1.0);

            _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt0.x, pt0.y);
            _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(xTex0, 0.0);
            _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt1.x, pt1.y);
            _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(xTex1, 0.0);

            pt0 = pt1;
        }
```

This almost fixed everything, the only two problems I still have are:

- A few pixel columns between joins of textures are rendered strangely
- There is still a memory issue with drawing the texPos and Pos triangles

These can be seen in this photo: As you can see the frame rate has dropped drastically and continues to do so all through the game.

[image: Still Have Memory Issue]

## UPDATE 2

I reduced the width of each triangle strip to try and find what was going on at the texture repeat, and found out that for some reason that strip was filled with the whole of the background texture but reversed. After a small amount of thinking I realised this was because due to flooring here: `int hSegments = floorf((p1.x-p0.x)/kHillSegmentWidth);` we get that the last strip for each repetition goes just past the width of the texture, however as we are remove 1 while xTex1 is greater than one this sets this texCoords to 0.02 (or some other small number) where it should actually be 1.02 (This is difficult to understand, however it is correct). I thought this could be solved by using another if statement like so:

```
float xTex0 = pt0.x/512;
            float xTex1 = pt1.x/512;
            while (xTex0 > 1.0) {
                xTex0 -= 1.0;
            }
            while (xTex1 > 1.0) {
                xTex1 -= 1.0;
            }

            if (xTex1 < xTex0) {
                xTex1++;
            }


            _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt0.x, 0);
            _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(xTex0, 1.0);
            _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt1.x, 0);
            _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(xTex1, 1.0);

            _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt0.x, pt0.y);
            _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(xTex0, 0.0);
            _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt1.x, pt1.y);
            _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(xTex1, 0.0);
```

This works fine for the first triangle in that strip, but not for the second for some peculiar reason, which I can't fathom at all! It looks like this: [image]

However the setup within _hillTexCoords seems correct, when I set a break point within the app this is the result I get for the _hillTexCoords array, and it looks like it should be pinning the texture correctly, but it still isn't (Incredibly frustrating!)

```
[44]    CGPoint (x=0.804036,y=1)
[45]    CGPoint (x=0.873047,y=1)
[46]    CGPoint (x=0.804036,y=0)
[47]    CGPoint (x=0.873047,y=0)
[48]    CGPoint (x=0.873047,y=1)
[49]    CGPoint (x=0.939453,y=1)
[50]    CGPoint (x=0.873047,y=0)
[51]    CGPoint (x=0.939453,y=0)
[52]    CGPoint (x=0.939453,y=1)
[53]    CGPoint (x=1.00586,y=1)
[54]    CGPoint (x=0.939453,y=0)
[55]    CGPoint (x=1.00586,y=0)
[56]    CGPoint (x=0.00585938,y=1)
[57]    CGPoint (x=0.0722656,y=1)
[58]    CGPoint (x=0.00585938,y=0)
[59]    CGPoint (x=0.0722656,y=0)
[60]    CGPoint (x=0.0722656,y=1)
[61]    CGPoint (x=0.13737,y=1)
[62]    CGPoint (x=0.0722656,y=0)
[63]    CGPoint (x=0.13737,y=0)
```

It's easy to see that the overlap from one texture back to the start of the texture follows the same pattern as the others, but it still doesn't render correctly!

## Update 3

It turns out that my memory issue is entirely unrelated to drawing using Opengl-es 2.0, it is in fact related to the box2D elements of my game not being de-allocated in the memory, so I have created a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023737/box2d-memory-not-freed-when-destroy-body) for this... I am still however, looking for a fix to the texture degradation problem!

Comment: I can't find any answers to this online, or any people who have also tried to port it to Cocos2D 2.0. There must be some interest in this out there? There's certainly a large interest in this method using Cocos2D 1.0... If anyone even has an inkling of an idea please help :D

Comment: This probably isn't your issue, but I don't think you should be using an increment operator on a float.

Comment: Very good point... Hope to high heaven it is my problem!!

Comment: Look suspiciously like you're trying to wrap the texture co-ordinates within a continuous TRIANGLE_STRIP.

Comment: Sorry for deleting previous comments. I don't want to overflow comments. Is that else in your last code snippet intentional? Remove it. That breaks your triangle degeneration pattern (you know you are degenerating your triangles, don´t you?) And i guess it creates a triangle just the way you show it =D

Comment: @JasonD I'm not sure quite whether I know what you mean saying that I'm trying to wrap the texture co-ordinates within a continuous strip... That's exactly what I'm trying to do, as If I don't the texture degenerates as the game goes along...

Teitus yeah my bad that else shouldn't be there, and in fact isn't in my code must have somehow ended up typo'ing it! Not sure what you mean by degenerating my triangles?

Comment: my mystake now, you are not degenerating triangles. I'll try to sketch something into an answer where I have more space. There is something that i dont understand in your code, which I'll post// (to degenerate a triangle is to send the same point consecutively so it's not rendered)

Comment: Cheers @Teitus! Look forward to trying your ideas :)

Comment: @simonthumper How did you get rid of the misalignment (see your image in update 1 "record distance 1915") ? Instead of using any of the code changes you made, I just made the change from JasonD's answer which solved the degradation, but once in a while there is a misalignment like your image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The triangle strip you generate for the visible part of the terrain will have texture coordinates which increase from left to right. When these get very large, you will have precision issues.

For your UV coordinates, you need to subtract the *same* value from all the coordinates in your triangle strip. Generally, take the integer part of the lowest coordinate (probably the far-left or first coordinate in your case), and subtract that from all the UVs you generate. Or use it as a baseline to generate the others, whichever you prefer.

So if the left hand side of the screen has a U value of 100.7 and the right hand side has a U value of 129.5, you actually want to output values ranging from 0.7 to 29.5. (if you still have precision issues, you might squeak out a bit more by centring the range on zero, using negative co-ords).

The alternative, if you need to have a discontinuity in the texture coordinates within a single strip, and to get maximum precision, is to introduce degenerate triangles, which are zero-area, and thus don't get rendered, while you change the tex-coords. You do that by repeating vertices, but with the adjusted tex-coords, before continuing.

Based on your code above, I'd suggest something like this:

```
// This line should happen only once per-strip. 
float U_Off = floor(pt0.x / 512);

// The inner loop then looks like this:
for (int j=1; j<hSegments+1; j++) {
    pt1.x = p0.x + j*dx;
    pt1.y = ymid + ampl * cosf(da*j);
    _borderVertices[_nBorderVertices++] = pt1;
    float xTex0 = pt0.x/512 - U_Off;
    float xTex1 = pt1.x/512 - U_Off;

    _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt0.x, 0);
    _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(xTex0, 1.0);
    _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt1.x, 0);
    _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(xTex1, 1.0);

    _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt0.x, pt0.y);
    _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(xTex0, 0.0);
    _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt1.x, pt1.y);
    _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(xTex1, 0.0);

    pt0 = pt1;
}
```

Comment: by UV coordinates do you mean the coordinates stored in `_hillVertices[]`? 

- if so surely taking values off of these will cause the texture to not move along with the terrain? As It will make the texture non-stationary w.r.t the ball... 

- if not what do you mean by my UV coordinates? Could you possibly write me a bit of code to show me what you mean? :)

Comment: By UV coords, I mean the texture coords, the ones in _hillTexCoords[]. You only subtract the integer part of the UV coords. The texture is mapped from 0 -> 1, and repeats outside of that range.

Comment: I am mapping the texture from 0 -> 1 (See update 1) I may just be tired::P but I don't see what is different from me mapping the texture from 0 to 1 like I am doing and what you are saying :/

Comment: hmmm I think I may have got you actually thinking about it... gimme a second

Comment: The trouble is you're trying to adjust mid-strip, which results in the interpolation across triangles being wrong where the adjustment happens. I've posted some code to show what I mean in the context of your app.

Comment: This essentially accomplishes what I had before... I don't get any loss in quality of the texture, but I still get a wrongly textured triangle for the second triangle in the last strip :/

Comment: Ah, you have an outer loop around this - then the offset should be outside that loop.

Comment: So the problem basically was that I was updating xTex0 and xTex1 mid-strip?

Comment: Yes, basically. At some point there was a triangle with tex-coords *miles* apart.

Answer (score 4):

This is just my guess... Not a solution, but a possible explanation.

I tried to trace how you are generating your mesh. At first I though you were doing some kind of intentional degeneration (as you are using a triangle strip, and using 4 vertices for each 2 triangles). But you are creating your mesh like this, right?.

```
3 ___ 4-7___ 8
| \    | \   |
|  \   |  \  |
1 ___ 2-5 __ 6
```

This creates triangles 123, [234], 345, [456], 567, [678]... and so on (note [] means reversed).  So, you see that you are overlapping half of the triangles. I suppose the last triangle drawn is seen and the other is hidden... providing z is exactly 0 you are not having any artifact.
When  4 = 7, and 2 = 5, which is when you are not modifying your texutre coordinate, everything works fine, as that, one way or another reduces to the following (which would be the correct way of doing it if you traspose it - acbdef). Translated to coordinates - same coordinate, same point it's like this:

```
c ___ d ___ f
| \   | \   |
|  \  |  \  |
a ___ b ___ e
```

In the log you posted, you write 4 points at a time, right? So, in the 13th cycle of the "for" you generate this vertexes: (14*3 = 52):

```
    [52]    CGPoint (x=0.939453,y=1) //1
    [53]    CGPoint (x=1.00586,y=1)  //2
    [54]    CGPoint (x=0.939453,y=0) //3
    [55]    CGPoint (x=1.00586,y=0)  //4

    [56]    CGPoint (x=0.00585938,y=1) //5
```

That makes 5 triangles. In particular 2 are of interest here: [234] and 345. 234 is ok, but 345 must be hiding it (because it renders after the other¿?. Try using an depth test function like GL_GREATER just to avoid it to render and see if i'm right on this one). Well, 345 is not right, it maps the texture from x= 0.07 to 1.00. So, even if you corrected 234, 345 is still drawn over your correct triangle. That should explain your background reversed thing.

So, that was what i think is the problem (wouldn't happen if you didn't normalize your texture coordinates like in the tutorial).

Do I still have to write the solution?? :/

To begin with, I'd suggest you generated your mesh like what i draw at second place (a,b,c...). Then continue with a solution. A **dirty** solution would be to degenarte the evil triangle 345. That would be to repeat point 4 one time (i'm a little dizzy rigth now, could be wrong )- Anyway this is not a good solution, you are mixing orientations and overlapping triangles. Each for iteration you should only add

```
        _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt0.x, 0);
        _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(xTex0, 1.0);

        _hillVertices[_nHillVertices] = CGPointMake(pt0.x, pt0.y);
        _hillTexCoords[_nHillVertices++] = CGPointMake(xTex0, 0.0);
```

Let me think a clean solution, or let somebody write it for me - Providing this is in fact, the problem.

Comment: Ahhhh yes that explains a lot! I've marked JasonD's answer as correct I'm afraid as he gave me an easier to implement solution. My problem in solving this myself was that I didn't realise I was drawing triangles 123, [234], 345, [456], 567, [678] as you correctly pointed out, I kind of assumed it was drawing 123,[234],567,[678] e.t.c which is why, I guess, I was going wrong! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I'm glad i helped. I know this was no solution, just an explanation for the curious. In fact, you could redraw your mesh like I said here (half number of triangles benefit), and set texture coords like JasonD pointed out. That would be an almost optimal soution! ;)